# Is it possible to ask for confirmation before removing a list item?

Tags: jquery, html

I have some code that can make a list, when you click on a list item it gets removed, however I'd like it to ask for confirmation before removing it.
I have no idea how to do this

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
        $('form').submit(function() {
            if ($('.input').val() !== '') {
                var newTask = $('.input').val();
                var newLi = $('<li>' + newTask + '</li>');
                newLi.on('click', function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
                $('ul').prepend(newLi);
                $('.input').val('');
                return false;
            }
        });
        $('ul').sortable(); :)
    });
```

Comment: Search for `confirm()`

Comment: Check https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp

Answer (score 0):

To ask form confirmation you can use the `confirm()` dialog. It's modal and will return `true` or `false` depending on the option the user clicked on.

Also note that you can make a couple of code improvements here. Firstly use a single delegated event handler instead of binding a new handler on every `li` you create. Secondly call `preventDefault()` on the `submit` event instead of returning `false`. Lastly, cache the `.input` selector instead of making a DOM request each time it's needed. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
      $(this).remove();
    }
  })

  var $input = $('.input');

  $('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($input.val() !== '') {
      var newTask = $('.input').val();
      $('ul').prepend('<li>' + newTask + '</li>');
      $input.val('');
    }
  });

  $('ul').sortable();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in [confirm()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) which returns a boolean value.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('li').on('click', function() {
    if (confirm('Please confirm to delete')) {
      $(this).remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this

```
function() {
     if (confirm("confirmation text")) {
        $(this).remove();
     }
}
```